# Problem with too many dimensions when the training of the ANN starts

Tags: python, tensorflow

I had no problems with my dataset and also with the code. I now just changed a few parameters like the Batch Size. I also uploaded everything to Google Colab.

Now I always get this message:

> enter de
>   /tensorflow-2.1.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py:677 map_fn
>           batch_size=None)
>       /tensorflow-2.1.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py:2410
>   _standardize_tensors
>           exception_prefix='input')
>       /tensorflow-2.1.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py:573
>   standardize_input_data
>           'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
>
> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_2_input to have 3
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (None, 1)

Can someone explain me, why this problem happens and what I can do?
PS. I am not an expert and can maybe give you more from the code.

```
simple_lstm_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.LSTM(8, input_shape=x_train_uni.shape[-2:]),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)])                                  
simple_lstm_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

Comment: Please provide your training code, along with input/output shapes.

Comment: @Andre: Can you try adding `Keras Embedding Laye`r before `LSTM Layer` and check if the Error Still Persists. If the issue still persists, can you please provide more code so that we can help. Thanks!